# Dynamically changing views

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view

I have a radioGroup which has 4 buttons namely 1,2,3,4,5.

If the user clicks radioButton 1, the view should show a different layout view in the same activity below the radio group. If the user clicks 2, it should show some other layout view. My aim is to change the view within the same layout and activity based on the selected radioButton.

I can change the textview's text based on different radioButtons.

That's easy !.

But what about changing the whole view ?

Comment: If the views are not complex put them in the layout and set visiblity to GONE after the radio selected set appropriate view visibility to Visible

Comment: But my views are like occupying the whole view

Comment: Sorry I did't get it can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I have five different layouts each one for each radioButton. If i clicked a radioButton, the appropriate layout should be inflated on my activity layout. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like this, I like to use a Frame layout below the radio group for a Fragment container

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkedButton="@id/net_sales_radio_button">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_one"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_two"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_three"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"
                    />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_four"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"
                    />

            </RadioGroup>


             <FrameLayout
                android:id = "@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

From here you can easily use Fragment transactions to switch out your layout depending on which radio button is selected.

```
Fragment fragment = new LogInFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
```

I prefer this approach over simply including the layouts in the parent layout for a few reasons.

1. because it allows you to keep your Activity's code more clean, since the code pertaining to each child layout will exist in their on Fragment, away from the parent Activity.
2. It also keeps your parent Activities XML file clean since you don't have to worry about putting a bunch of `<include>` tags or other views pertaining to the child layouts.

If you want to access the edittext of the Fragments within the MainActivity, here is a cool technique.

1. Create an interface class that will return a value for each edittext the Fragments have. Below I have created one for if your Fragments had user data. If there are a lot of edittexts in your Fragments and you don't want to have a lot of functions in your interface, create a model class that has the fields you need and have the interface return that one model.

```
public interface FormCallbacks {
    String getUserName();
    String getAddress();
    String getPhone();
}
```

2. Have each of your Fragments implement the interface and in the callback methods return the value for your edit texts

```
public class UserOneFragment extends Fragment implements FormCallbacks {

    private EditText etUserName;
    private EditText etAddress;
    private EditText etPhone;

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return etUserName.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAddress() {
        return etAddress.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPhone() {
        return etPhone.getText().toString();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

3. Access the callbacks from your MainActivity

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment instanceof FormCallbacks) {
            FormCallbacks callbacks = (FormCallbacks) fragment;
            String userName = callbacks.getUserName();
            String address = callbacks.getAddress();
            String phone = callbacks.getPhone();
        }
```

Comment: Can I access the widgets inside the fragment from my Main Activity ?

Comment: Becoz I wanna get the value from the Edit Text that's inside the fragment and do a common operation in my Main Activity

Comment: Yeah Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onCheckedChangeListener()` on the radio group.

```
radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedRadioId ->

            when (checkedRadioId) {
                radioOne.id -> {
                    //inflate your desired view
                }
                radioTwo.id -> {
                    //inflate your second view
                }
            }
        }
```

To inflate new view,

```
var view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.newlayout, null) as LinearLayout
container.addView(view)
```

As these `views` can overshoot the screen hight, you can put your parent view inside `scrollview`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Can I access the widget inside the inflated view from my activity class ?

Comment: Yes, you can access all the widgets.

Comment: Yeah Thank you :)